# Round to two decimal places only if repeating python

Tags: python, rounding, fractions

I was wondering if anybody knew of a quick way in python to check and see if a fraction gives a repeating decimal.

I have a small function that takes in two numbers and divides them.  If the quotient is a repeating decimal I would like to round to 2 decimal places and if the quotient is not repeating I would like to round to just one

Example:

800/600 = 1.33333333333333 which would equal 1.33

900/600 = 1.5 would stay as 1.5

I know that I need to use the two statements for the two types of rounding

```
output = "{:.2f}".format(float(num))
output = "{:,}".format(float(num))
```

but I am having trouble with the if statement to direct to one or the other.

Can anybody help with some insight?

Comment: All fractions can be written using repeating decimals. Do the division like you did in school and check for immediate repeating pattern.

Comment: What do you want printed for 1/1? or 5/4?

Comment: Ah sorry this may have been a stupid question.  For 1/1 I would like to show 1 and for 5/4 I would show 1.25.  My goal is not to show any trailing 0s

Comment: What do you want for 10/99, which goes 0.101010...?

Comment: I would like to see 10/99 = 0.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module, which implements exact rational arithmetic:

```
import fractions

# fractions.Fraction instances are automatically put in lowest terms.
ratio = fractions.Fraction(numerator, denominator)
```

You can then inspect the `denominator` of the result:

```
def is_repeating(fraction):
    denom = fraction.denominator
    while not (denom % 2):
        denom //= 2
    while not (denom % 5):
        denom //= 5
    return denom != 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Just use brute force. Since you want only 2 decimal places. Just divide and then test it when it is rounded to 0 and 1 decimal place and see where it stops being unique. If it is not unique at this point, then round to 2 decimal places.

```
def f(x):
    if x == round(x,0):
        return '{:.0f}'.format(x)
    elif x == round(x,1):
        return '{:.1f}'.format(x)
    else:
        return round(x,2)

y = [1, 2, 3, 3/2, 1/9, 8/9, 1/11, 12/11, 10/11, 14/13, 1/3]
for item in y:
    print(f(item))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
1.5
0.11
0.89
0.09
1.09
0.91
1.08
0.33
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a workaround using regex :)

```
import re

result = str(800/600)
# result = str(900/600)

repeating_pair = re.escape(result.split('.')[1][:2])
check_within = result.split('.')[1][2:]

if re.match(repeating_pair, check_within):
    print("{:.2f}".format(float(result)))
else:
    print("{:.1f}".format(float(result)))
```

Output:

```
1.33
```

And for `900/600`

```
1.5
```

Answer (score -1):

> repeating decimal

There are only 10 fractions that can be written as some repeated digit - `.(0)`, `.(1)`, ... `.(9)`. Thus, if you only care about repeating pattern starting right after decimal point, you only need to check against those cases.

All those numbers (and only them) give an integer if multiplied by 9.

Thus, if `(9 * numenator) % denominator == 0`, you'll print 2 digits.

You'll probably want to exclude `.(0)` pattern though. To do that, test if your fraction is in fact an integer - `numenator % denominator == 0`.

Also check out [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) module in case you have some wheels to reinvent.

Of course, if you only have your number as a `float`, there is some ambiguity about what numenator and denominator are, because `float`s don't actually store rational numbers like `1/3`. You can experiment with `fractions`'s `.limit_denominator()` to choose something that works for your case.

Comment: "repeating decimal" includes numbers like 1/7 and 10/99. The repeating part doesn't have to be a single digit.

Comment: That would mean printing `900/600` as `1.50`, which is not the case in OP's examples.

Comment: 900/600 is terminating.

Comment: It *does* have a repeating decimal - 0 - which is the distinction in the question.
However, any fraction has one, but not any fractional part has decimal representation composed solely of this pattern. `1.5(0)` has its '5', so it's truncated.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what the term "repeating decimal" means, and perhaps more importantly, your usage of the term does not match the questioner's intent. As an example, the questioner wants `0.10` for 10/99, which has a repeating component 2 digits long.

Comment: I am using interpretation under which both examples in the question are relevant to the distinction described in question and under which the questoin makes sense. Sure the interpretation may be wrong but I can not divine the intent, I only have the text. For your example, same approach with 99 instead of 9 can be used.